# When porting a new project from Spring Initializr to IntelliJ IDEA, how do you get the java files to recognize what's in the POM?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I've been following along in Chad Darby's Spring udemy course. He ported a new project from Spring Initializr to IntelliJ community edition and it automatically recognized what he had set up in the POM. Mine is giving me an error message:

> java: package org.springframework.boot does not exist

Mycoolapplication.java reads:

```java
package com.luv2code.springboot.demo.mycoolapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MycoolappApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MycoolappApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

and the POM reads:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-M3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.luv2code.springboot.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>mycoolapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mycoolapp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

What am I doing wrong, and how am I supposed to create a new project ported from Spring Initializr?

Comment: Just import the maven project, as a maven project.

Comment: Try to close the project with `File | Close Project`, close the IDE. Open the project in the OS file managed and delete all .iml files and the .idea folder. Re-import your project to the IDE by selecting pom.xml file